# How can I share database android application and a .net web application?

Tags: android, database, iis, remote-server

I want to share database between an android application and a web application build using Asp.net (my database is based on an IIS server.)
I just want to find the possible ways available to do it, and if I could use php services with IIS server.

I would be so thankful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Million ways. I can advise you this one: create REST or SOAP service which will have access to database with all methods you need. Now in android application and in ASP.NET application you can "ask" your service to create/update/delete/do something.

Comment: Thanks @dikkini for your quick answer, sorry but since I'm beginner I don't know if I could use php REST services with an IIS server?

Answer (score 0):

try with below code.Hope it will resolved your query.

```
/**
 * This method is used for getting user response after sending request to server. 
 * It returns the response after executing url request.
 * @param params
 * @return
 */
public  String  getJSONObject(String params)
    {
        try
        {
             URL url = null;
             String response = null;
             String parameters = "param1=value1&param2=value2";
             //url = new URL("http://www.somedomain.com/sendGetData.php");
             url = new URL(params);
             //create the connection
             HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             connection.setDoOutput(true);
             connection.setReadTimeout(40000);
             connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
             //set the request method to GET
             connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
             //get the output stream from the connection you created
             OutputStreamWriter request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
             //write your data to the ouputstream
             request.write(parameters);
             request.flush();
             request.close();
             String line = "";
             //create your inputsream
             InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                     connection.getInputStream());
             //read in the data from input stream, this can be done a variety of ways
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 sb.append(line + "\n");
             }
             //get the string version of the response data
             response = sb.toString();
             //do what you want with the data now

             //always remember to close your input and output streams 
             isr.close();
             reader.close();
         } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("HTTP GET:", e.toString());
            response="";
         }

        return response;
   }
```